# В чем разница между Blazor и ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, blazor

Я даже не знаю задал ли я правильно вопрос. Хочу изучать создание сайтов на C#. Понял, что на этих фреймворках можно создать сайт. Но в чем разница, не понимаю.

Comment: ASP.NET Core - клиентская часть пишется на JavaScript, Blazor - клиентская часть пишется на C#.

Comment: Blazor - это тоже ASP.NET Core, точнее одна из технологий на основе ASP.NET Core.  Blazor отличается тем, что не нужно ничего писать на JavaScript, все запросы клиента отрабатываются на сервере, т.е. код пишется на C#.

Comment: https://blazorschool.com/tutorial вот тут есть про блазор очень хорошие примеры, документация